# How to give columns inside a panel fixed column widths?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

What's the best Swing layout if I want to have a set of columns with fixed column span inside a panel?

Something like below:

[image: desired column layout]

I would like the first column to span 20% of the width of the panel, the second column to span 50% of the panel and the third column to span 30% of the width of the panel

Comment: `GridBagLayout` would be a starting point, although, I'd consider spending some time looking at `JTable`  just to be sure

Comment: There is no layout manager in the JDK that allocates spaces relatively. GridBagLayout comes close. It will first allocate space based on the preferred size. Then if there is extra space available, it will allocate the extra space in the relative weightings you provide. Read up on the `weightx` constraint found in [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). Or you could use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) which does allow you to allocate space relatively to each component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great visual guide for layouts in Java Swing on [Oracle's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) website.

For your case, [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#gridbag) would be your best option even though it's the most complex. There are other layouts that you could get away with although it depends on what you are actually trying to do. You can look at the [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#grid), the [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#box), the [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border) and even the default layout ([FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow)) could work.

You could also look at JTable because you write about columns and I noticed the little circle on the left that kind of look like an index number or something, but I could be wrong. Maybe you are trying to do a sort of table...

Answer (score 0):

My result:

[image: My result]

You can use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) library it is a useful for java layout
for my sample code

```
 panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
 panel.add(new JTextField(), "w 20%");
 panel.add(new JTextField(), "w 50%");
 panel.add(new JTextField(), "w 30%");
```